# Why are my PCs and Mac not able to transfer to each other?

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, macbook-pro

They're all connected to the internet but aren't able to talk to each other. I'm having difficulties in logging in to the other computer to access it.

In Windows I use this to access the network.:

```
run \\192.168.0.123
```

In Mac I use this to access the network.:

```
smb:\\192.168.0.123
```

From my Desktop and MBP I am able to connect to both Dell laptops. 
I'm just not able to access my Desktop and MBP from any computer or laptop. When I'm trying to access Desktop or MBP it will just ask me for my "Account Name" and "Password" but will not accept it. I've tried simplifying my password and account name for my Desktop and MBP so I wouldn't get a typo error. But still no success.

All PCs are running Windows 7. Two Dell Inspiron 1440 and one Desktop Computer.
My Mac Book Pro is running Lion (Mac OX 10.7.2).

Below is a diagram of how my computers are connected.

[image: network]

Here is an overview of how their connections work and fail:

- MBP ⟶ 2 Dell Inspiron 1440 = success!
- Desktop ⟶ 2 Dell Inspiron 1440 = success!
- 1 Inspiron 1440 ⟶ 1 Inspiron 1440 = success!
- Inspiron 1440 ⟶ MBP = fail!
- Inspiron 1440 ⟶ Desktop = fail!
- MBP ⟶ Desktop = fail!
- Desktop ⟶ MBP = fail!

What do you think is the problem? Do I miss some permissions settings or something?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need each user account (+password) entered into 'User Accounts' on each PC so there is a locally authorised account for any network access. Also having the same Workgroup entered will help with 'discovering' local computers. I'm unsure what settings you can change to remedy the Mac side of things but check what settings are within 'Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Network and Sharing Center\Advanced sharing settings' on the Windows 7 machines.

Comment: I've setup all user accounts on each computer. for the Workgroup, i think it's configured properly as I can access my other laptop from my desktop. It's just when i try accessing my desktop from my inspiron 1440 just fails. Thanks!

Comment: Verify on the desktop that Network discovery is On in sharing settings (see above), you could also try turning on public folder sharing to see if that prompts it into appearing! Goodluck! :)

Comment: I've check the PCs and they're all enabled to share folder. 

Here's some of my theory.
Since my desktop uses Lan to the router, do you think that's where the problem is? The problem only occurs when I'm trying to access the Desktop from other computer. In the otherhand its also fine when  i'm accessing the other pcs from my desktop.

Comment: for my Mac, I can't also access it from other computer.