# Networking Software connecting mac to pc

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

Is there a software the automate network configuration or setup everything you need to connect computer-to-computer?

Something like a dropbox but doesn't need to be online.

Let say you need to connect:

1 - Desktop PC running on Windows 7

1 - Router

2 - Laptop running on Windows 7

1 - Macbook Pro running on Lion (10.7.2)

This question is related to my previous question here: [Why are my PCs and Mac not able to transfer to each other?](https://superuser.com/questions/364693/why-are-my-pcs-and-mac-not-able-to-transfer-to-each-other)

My main problem in my previous question is, I'm not able to connect to my Desktop that is running on Windows 7 (32 bit) and my Macbook Pro (2011) that is running on Lion 10.7.2.

But I'm able to connect on other computer on the network from my Desktop and Macbook.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: What are you calling "Connecting" ? Transfering files ? That's SMB job (SAMBA under linux, Network Shares under Windows, Connect to server under OSX). If you are talking about network configuration (IP, DNS, etc.) that's DHCP's job (your router should handle that). Be more specific.

Comment: Actually I'm not sure what's the problem. For this question, I just need a solution where I can share files in my network without relying on the internet. It should also be cross-platform. basically similar to Dropbox is offering, but dropbox is relying on the internet to be able to sync files.

Comment: In my previous question, the main problem is on my Macbook Pro and Desktop. They can't be accessed by other computer, but can access other computers. 

so if it's Desktop to other laptop it would work. but if I try accessing my Desktop from other laptop it wouldn't work. It also applies on my macbook pro, I can access other computers but I'm not able to access from other computer or laptop.

Comment: So my guess is, I may have a setting on my Desktop or Macbook Pro that does not allow other users to access it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is too broad to be answered here, but I understand you are trying to access shared filesystems accross your local network. That's SMB protocol's job (so like I said, SAMBA under linux, Network Shares under Windows, Connect to Server under OSX). It can however be tricky to get it working flawlessly between different implementations and OSes. As a starting point, do not try to use anonymous accesses (no user/password), that's insecure and rarely works between different implementations easily. And read each implementation's documentation, and/or google the answer ([this one](http://www.trickyways.com/2011/07/file-sharing-mac-os-x-lion-and-pc-windows-7/) seems correct). Hope that helps.